# Scheduling Perl Script in Cron.d

Tags: cron, perl, opensuse, awstats

I am trying to schedule a perl script to run daily, but I am not sure if I am doing everything right.

The script I want to run is to update AWStats each day, without manually having to press update.

Currently, I created a file in the cron.d folder with the following text inside:

```
00 09 * * * /usr/local/awstats/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=cwp-dev-02
```

If I run:

```
/usr/local/awstats/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=cwp-dev-02
```

The stats update succesfully, but nothing seems to happen with the scheduled task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't copy such files directly into `cron.d` - instead use the *crontab(1)* command to inject new commands.

Suppose your entries are in a file named `mycrontab`:

```
 $ crontab mycrontab
```

and you're done

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to include a username in the job spec e.g.

```
00 09 * * * root /usr/local/awstats/cgi-bin/awstats.pl -config=cwp-dev-02
```

because the files in /etc/cron.d are treated in the same way as the /etc/crontab file.
Also check that only root can write to the file.